# The output in wrapped function isn't printed between decorator

Tags: python, python-3.x

I don't know why the output in wrapped function hasn't been printed among decorator, my codes as below:

```
from functools import wraps
checkresultfile = './checkres1.log'
def log_detection_res(detect_items=''):
    def process_reminder_decorator(check_func):
        @wraps(check_func)
        def addingReminder(*args, **kwargs):
            process_begin_reminder = "=" * 10 + detect_items + "begin" + "=" * 10
            process_stop_reminder = "=" * 10 + detect_items + "end" + "=" * 10
            with open(checkresultfile, 'a') as res_file:
                res_file.write(process_begin_reminder + '\n')
                check_func(*args, **kwargs)
                res_file.write(process_stop_reminder + '\n')
            return check_func
        return addingReminder
    return process_reminder_decorator

@log_detection_res(detect_items='srlg conflict detection')
def relay_srlg_conflict_detect():
    tplt = "{0:^30}\t{1:^20}\t{2:^20}\t{3:^10}\t{4:^20}\t{5:^20}\t{6:^20}\t{7:^20}\t{8:^10}"
    output_file.write(
        tplt.format("Conflict_Index", "INGRESS", "EGRESS", "Index", "Fault_Node", "Fault_link", "Router_Node",
                    "Route_link", "SRLG") + "\n")

with open(checkresultfile, 'a') as output_file:
    relay_srlg_conflict_detect()
```

The output in file is:

```
==========srlg conflict detection begin==========
==========srlg conflict detection end==========
        Conflict_Index                INGRESS                  EGRESS             Index          Fault_Node              Fault_link             Router_Node              Route_link            SRLG
```

what I am expecting is:

```
==========srlg conflict detection begin==========
  Conflict_Index                  INGRESS                  EGRESS             Index          Fault_Node              Fault_link             Router_Node              Route_link            SRLG  
==========srlg conflict detection end==========
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem is that you are trying to open on the same time the same file

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import time

from functools import wraps

checkresultfile = './checkres1.log'


def log_detection_res(detect_items=''):
    def process_reminder_decorator(check_func):
        @wraps(check_func)
        def addingReminder(*args, **kwargs):
            process_begin_reminder = "=" * 10 + detect_items + "begin" + "=" * 10
            process_stop_reminder = "=" * 10 + detect_items + "end" + "=" * 10
            with open(checkresultfile, 'a') as res_file:
                res_file.write(process_begin_reminder + '\n')
                check_func(output_file=res_file, *args, **kwargs)
                res_file.write(process_stop_reminder + '\n')
            return check_func

        return addingReminder

    return process_reminder_decorator


@log_detection_res(detect_items='srlg conflict detection')
def relay_srlg_conflict_detect(output_file):
    tplt = "{0:^30}\t{1:^20}\t{2:^20}\t{3:^10}\t{4:^20}\t{5:^20}\t{6:^20}\t{7:^20}\t{8:^10}"
    output_file.write(
        tplt.format("Conflict_Index", "INGRESS", "EGRESS", "Index", "Fault_Node", "Fault_link", "Router_Node",
                    "Route_link", "SRLG") + "\n")


relay_srlg_conflict_detect()
```

output

```
==========srlg conflict detectionbegin==========
        Conflict_Index                INGRESS                  EGRESS             Index          Fault_Node              Fault_link             Router_Node              Route_link            SRLG   
==========srlg conflict detectionend==========
```

Comment: Thanks Beny , the way of your realization really refreshed my cognition. The defination of function has taken a formal parameter `output_file` , but you missed it when executed the   function and the programe well executed , could you please share me a knowledge ink or some else to explain the funtion excuted without taken a parameter where it was defined